# Controlling Fans on an HP Probook 4525s

Tags: 14.04, power-management, fan

I would like to simply set my fan to run at 100% speed all the time. Is there any way to do this without fancontrol? Is there a way to physically make the fan run at all times (external power?) or would it be better to buy a cooling pad/external fan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't want to mess with power settings inside the computer just to make the fan run at 100% all the time.  (you did specify 'without fan control')

If your BIOS doesn't support running fans at 100% all the time (it does on some HP servers) I would *definitely* go for an external fan!

Comment: I thought as much. I just ordered an external fan on Amazon and it should arrive in a few days. Thanks!

Comment: Pease don't thank me, just press the little check-mark below the number 0 and it will turn green and that's the best "thank you" you can give me.